# Obstacle Avoidance with Point Cloud Library

Tags: kinect, point-cloud-library

I've been developing a system that aims at detecting obstacles (with Kinect) and then according to the Kinect perspective, finding the non-obstacle side. I am using Point Cloud Library since I am working with depth data. So far, i was able to make floor segmentation, some downsamplings (voxel grid, passthrough) and clustering (potential obstacles). Final stage of my work is to find safe route (non-obstacle side). But I am not sure how can i get the horizontal bounds (x axis) of Kinect perspective to decide the exact location of obstacles in the scene.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I am unsure of the problem. If you are working at every stage in the camera's frame of reference ("Kinect perspective"), then surely getting the axis-aligned bounding box (minimum and maximum x, y and z valuse) of the obstacles would be enough? The question seems to suggest that there is only the one frame of reference being considered?

Comment: If i get the maximum and minimum boundries of the obstacles, how could i decide about obstacle for example "It's on close-left,middle,far-right etc.".That's the point I wonder about: Is there any reference system corresponding to the scene. Does 0.0.0 refer to the origin of the scene?

Comment: What is it that needs to avoid obstacles? Where is the camera with respect to that thing? Do you need a qualitative output "close-left" or numeric?

Comment: To answer your last question: If we are considering the coordinate frame of the camera then the origin is usually at the camera aperture - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinhole_camera_model

Comment: The camera is supposed to be carried by on a person's head.(on the helmet). I will divide the horizontal axis by 5: far left-left-middle-right-far right. The system should find the safe side and inform the user about it. This thing must work in real time.

Comment: There are a lot of ways you could do this. I suggest you take an initial stab and then improve it. e.g. simply count the number of points within a certain range in each sector and threshold to determine presence of obstacle. Use some trig to find the angle of the point to the yz plane. Once you have then you can make it more clever (consider density of points, try and recognise objects, etc.).

Comment: We turn back the first problem :) How can i define the limits of sectors?

Comment: Well you could just examine the x coordinates of the points would be the simplest way (this is not strictly sectors though). Alternative use some trig to calculate the angle with the z axis.

Comment: is x=0 value is the middle point of the horizontal axis?

Comment: Yes x=0 will be the middle point. IIRC Kinect point cloud data is expressed in metres but I suggest you examine some of the data in the point cloud and play around a bit to get a feel for it (in particularly, create visualisations to see what is going on; PCLVisualizer is one tool that can be useful for this); also, see the reference frame information in the pinhole camera model page. It is the basic idea behind how the kinect produces its data.

Comment: Summarising from that article: z is distance in direction camera is pointing and y is vertical distance (according to camera frame of reference) of a point. If it is a right-handed coordinate system (which I suspect it might be) then a negative z value represents something in front of the camera and a positive z value represents something behind the camera - but don't take my word for that - take a look at the data.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm from Istanbul too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i found a solution. Here it is;

1-)I have divided the screen into 4 horizontal parts. Each part represents 0.75m gap that is sufficient to pass through easily by average human.

2-)To navigate user safe side, i count the number of points for each side (left or right).

3-)After 2nd step is done, i know the side that has few points. Then, in the side that has few points, i perform a sub-control. For example, if the right side has few points, then i calculate points in right side's sub sides (close right,far right).

4-) Finally, the sub-side that has less points then the other sub side is transposed to user if it satisfies the number of points criteria ( if it contains 100 or less points)

Hope it would help someone else that is working on it.